# React JS 2 calls same component

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to React and I'm trying to loop over a set of Json objects using .map. I do 2 Json calls using Ajax and loop over the first.

Basically I would like to loop over the data from the first call, and include the second call data in the same map loop.

Example (blue = first call, red = second call):

[image]

So the image above is generated with the code below, while `this.props.data` is the result of the first Ajax call:

```
var firstLine = this.props.data.map(function(metric) {
    if(metric.line == 1) {
      return (
            <FirstLineBox name={metric.name} key={metric.name} value={metric.value} />
      );
    }
});
```

and the FirstLineBox

```
var FirstLineBox = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
        <div className="col-md-3 col-xs-6 text-center">
            <p className="leading-stats-number"><i className="fa fa-users"></i> {this.props.value}</p>
            <p className="pages-number-compare"><small><i className="fa fa-arrow-circle-up"></i> compare</small></p>
            <p className="pages-number-text"><small>{this.props.name}</small></p>           
        </div>
    );
  }
});
```

All good until here, but my goal is to have the result of the second call inside the red highlighted zone in the image, something like:

```
var FirstLineBox = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
        <div className="col-md-3 col-xs-6 text-center">
            <p className="leading-stats-number"><i className="fa fa-users"></i> {this.props.data.value}</p>
            <p className="pages-number-compare"><small><i className="fa fa-arrow-circle-up"></i> {this.props.data_compare.value}</small></p>
            <p className="pages-number-text"><small>{this.props.data.name}</small></p>              
        </div>
    );
  }
});
```

Is this achievable? I can control the response of the Json and merging the calls into one would be possible, however I prefer to have react handling it separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem is solved: it's not possible to accomplish what I was trying to do.

The way I solved it was by doing the 2 calls beforehand, merge and loop it.

Other way would be to do individual calls inside the loop but it's not an option in my case.

Thanks all.